# when run make install command in opensuse for install wine it not work

Tags: wine, opensuse

i need install wine in oensuse but
when run make install command in opensuse for install wine it not work

./configure and make and make dependency work well but make install dont work

error is :cant create new folder access is denied

i need guidelinefor install tar.gz  file in opensuse

tnx

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that this is software, rather than programming support, you need to run "make install" with root privileges:

```
sudo make install
```